# Simulating natural log of Ito process and divergence.

Tags: stochastic-processes, numerical-methods, stochastic-calculus

The issue comes from some simulations I'm running in which a process ($X_t$) should always be positive, but using an Euler-Murayama scheme allows the process to become negative. To alleviate the problem, I define a new process ($Z_t$) such that $X_t$ is the exponential of $Z_t$, ensuring that $X_t$ is always positive. However, the new process goes to zero "to fast", that is the numerical solution is clearly incorrect. Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Here is a more complete description:

Given an Ito process $X_t$ such that
$$
dX_t = \mu^X_t dt + \sigma^X_t dW_t
$$
When $dW_t$ has several negative realizations, an Euler-Murayama scheme allows $X_t$ to move into a region ($X_t < 0$) which is not allowed. This is driven by a large volatility $\sigma^X_t$.

To try to alleviate this problem, define a new process $Z_t$ such that $X_t = \exp Z_t$. Ito's lemma implies that
$$
\begin{align*}
dZ_t &= d(ln X_t)\\
&= \frac{dX_t}{X_t} - \frac{1}{2}\frac{(dX_t)^2}{X_t^2}\\
&= \left(\frac{\mu_t^X}{X_t} - \frac{1}{2}\frac{(\sigma^X_t)^2}{X_t^2}\right)dt + \frac{\sigma_t^X}{X_t} dW_t
\end{align*}
$$
Now $X_t \geq 0$, but the large volatility causes a different problem, namely a very negative drift in $Z_t$, which causes $Z_t$ to go to $-\infty$ very quickly and thus $X_t$ goes to zero very quickly, no matter the value of $W_t$.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to alleviate this issue? Is there some nice middle ground? Am I making a mistake?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me that if $X_t$ takes only positive values, then the model $\mathsf d X_t = \mu_t^X\mathsf dt + \sigma_t^X\mathsf dW_t$ is fundamentally incorrect...

Comment: This is a typical assumption in consumption based asset pricing, where $X_t$ is wealth and one assumes it is bounded from below. Under certain assumptions on preferences, it can be shown that it will never reach the bound, but only become infinitely close.